# Trying to Merge data from one table to another

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

Trying to do a process where I have a table that is existing. This is table A

I have staging table which I have uploaded the data. This is table B.

Table A already contains data in there apart from some data which i need added from table B to Table A.

So Table B has a extra column which I need it to match with the data already existing in Table A.

So layout currently in Table A is:

```
Column 1 Column 2 Column 3

AB

ABC
```

Layout in Table B is:

```
Column 1 Column 2 Column 3

ABC      Yellow   Test1

AB       Blue     Test2
```

So I need these columns 2 and 3 moved to table A from Table B, so they match correctly with the data that is already in column 1.

Tried my best to explain and english is my 2nd language, so i apologise for any mistakes. Anyway know what best way to go with this, would it be a merge?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
 Update TableA
 Set TableA.Column2=B.Column2,
       TableA.Column3=B.Column3
 From TableA A
      Inner Join TableB B ON B.Column1=A.Column1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Left Outer join to merge data

```
SELECT TableA.clomun1,
       Tableb.column2.tableb.column3                 
FROM tableA
     LEFT JOIN tableB
         ON table1.column1 = table2.column1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Following query is working fine in **MySQL** , try it out :

```
update TableA as a inner join TableB as b on a.Column1=b.Column1 
set a.Column2 = b.Column2 , a.Column3=b.Column3 
where a.Column1=b.Column1;
```

And for **Oracle** use this one :

```
update TableA 
set TableA.Column2 = 
(select TableB.Column2 from TableB where TableA.Column1=TableB.Column1), 
TableA.Column3 =
(select TableB.Column3 from TableB where TableA.Column1=TableB.Column1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
MERGE INTO TableA
USING (SELECT Column1, COlumn2, Column3
   FROM   TableB) Q
ON (TableA.Column1=TableB.Column1)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET TableA.Column2=Q.Column2
                           , TableA.Column3=Q.Column3;
```

This works fine in Oracle. You can also insert records that are not in Table A adding

```
 WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (Column1, Column2, Column3) 
              VALUES (Q.Column1, Q.Column2, Q.Column3)
```